# "Object doesn't support this property or method" when setting an object property in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm trying to make draggable elements without using jQuery. I'd like it to be compatible with IE8. The following breaks at `this.handle = {` with the error, "Object doesn't support this property or method."

Does IE9< have some goofy hang-up when it comes to setting object properties?

```
var Draggable = function(el){
  this.el = el;
  this.el.style.left = "0px";
  this.el.style.top = "0px";
  this.origin = {};

  this.handle = {
    drag: this.drag.bind(this),
    move: this.move.bind(this)
  };

  this.events = {
    start: new Listener(this.el, ["mousedown", "touchstart"], this.handle.drag),
    move: {},
    end: {}
  };
}
Draggable.prototype = {
  drag: function(evt){
    this.origin.left = parseInt(this.el.style.left) - evt.clientX;
    this.origin.top = parseInt(this.el.style.top) - evt.clientY;
    this.events.move = new Listener(window, ["mousemove", "touchmove"], this.handle.move);
    this.events.end = new Listener(window, ["mouseup", "touchend"], this.drop.bind(this));
  },
  move: function(evt){
    this.el.style.left = this.origin.left + evt.clientX + "px";
    this.el.style.top = this.origin.top + evt.clientY + "px";
  },
  drop: function(){
    this.events.move.stopListening();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Function.prototype.bind()` isn't supported in IE8. You can write a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill) for it.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. I solved it by doing `var self = this;`, which I'm not proud of.